# Display an image with OpenCV and input text over specific spots in C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, text

I'm looking to label specific x,y coordinates in my image with letter values. I saw that OpenCV has a "putText" function, but that only allows me to overlay text on one of the corners of the image. I have x,y coordinates where I'd like to overlay the text.

Is there any way to do this through OpenCV and if not, how might I do this?

Edit: clarification that I'm trying to do this in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cv::Point pt(x,y); // pixel coordinates
cv::putText( img, my_string, pt, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2.0, cv::Scalar(blue,green,red);
```

The 5th argument is a scale value, adjust on your needs
The color values are in the range (0-255), for a `CV_8UC3` image.

You have [additional fonts here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d0/de1/group__core.html#ga0f9314ea6e35f99bb23f29567fc16e11&gsc.tab=0).

These are the only requested arguments but you have more if needed, [see here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576).

Answer (score 0):

```
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(img,'OpenCV',(x,y), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

where font is the font and (x,y) is the coordinate of the text

C++: void putText(InputOutputArray img, const String& text, Point org, int fontFace, double fontScale, Scalar color, int thickness=1, int lineType=LINE_8, bool bottomLeftOrigin=false )

Pass org the point cordinates of the text